# C++ Autotools Google test framework

Tags: c++, autotools, googletest

I'm trying to add Google Test Framework to my app using autotools.
But i got some stange errors for me.
In configure.ac:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER([gtest/gtest.h], [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_GTEST_H], 1)])
```

But in log I got:

```
...
checking for limits.h... yes
checking gtest/gtest.h usability... no
checking gtest/gtest.h presence... no
checking for gtest/gtest.h... no
```

config.log:

```
configure:3276: checking gtest/gtest.h presence
configure:3276: gcc -E  conftest.c
In file included from conftest.c:19:0:
/usr/include/gtest/gtest.h:54:18: fatal error: limits: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Both files are exists. And as I know /usr/include is default include.

Comment: <Sarcastic>Clearly a bug in gcc!</sarcastic>
So, my guess is that either the files are not actually there, or not readable from the account you are using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<limits>` is a C++ header, which probably signifies `gtest.h` is a C++ header which means the Google Test framework is written in C++. You'll need to use the C++ compiler to detect the usability of the header.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6129834/256138) for details on how to work around this with autotools.